# Jquery move the rows to the left

Tags: jquery

I have got a problem with my jquery. I am using the keyboard arrow button control to allow me to move the yellow row to each row. I can't be able to move the second and third rows to the left to allow me to see the fourth rows from the right where it have been hidden.

Here is the current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetXmlHttpObject()
    {
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            return new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        return null;
    }

    var current_col = 1;
    var current_row = 1;

    $(document).keyup(function(event){
        var yellowbg = $(".yellowbg");
        var rowwidth = $(".row").css( "width").split("px");
        var yellowbgdivclass = yellowbg.attr('class');
        var splitclass = yellowbgdivclass.split(" ");
        var getcurrentrow = splitclass[1].split("_");

        var mainWraptop = $(".mainWrap").position().top;
        var mainWrapheight = $(".mainWrap").height();
        var rowmove=$("#rowmove").val();
        //alert($(".row").length);

        var displayrowcount = 6;  //is using for to hide other channels
        var rowheight = 42;
        var rowwidth = 1053;  //is using for how much width the row is going to display while hide the other rows
        var rowwidth1 = 1303;  //is using for how much width the row is going to display while hide the other rows
        var totalwidth_current = 0;
        var totalwidth_current1 = 0;

        if(parseInt(current_row)+parseInt(1) <=5)
        {
            for(var i=1; i<=(parseInt(current_row)+parseInt(1));i++ )
            {
                var yellowbgnextdivwidth = $(".div_"+current_col+'_'+i).css( "width"); 
                var yellowbgnextdivwidthsplit = yellowbgnextdivwidth.split("px");
                totalwidth_current=parseInt(totalwidth_current)+parseInt(yellowbgnextdivwidthsplit[0]);
            }
        }

        if (event.keyCode == 39) 
        {  //right
            if (yellowbg.next().length)
            {
                var currentrowleft = $(".rowSubPgm div.pgmFirstRow:first").css( "margin-left").split("px");
                currentrowleft1 = currentrowleft[0].split("-");
                currentrowleft2 = currentrowleft[0].split("-");

                if(typeof(currentrowleft2[1])!= "undefined")
                    currentrowleft = currentrowleft2[1];
                else if(typeof(currentrowleft1[1])!= "undefined")
                    currentrowleft = currentrowleft1[1];
                else
                    currentrowleft = currentrowleft[0];

                var nextdivwidth = $(".div_"+current_col+'_'+(parseInt(current_row)+parseInt(1))).css( "width").split("px");    

                //alert((parseInt(rowwidth)+parseInt(currentrowleft)));
                //alert(totalwidth_current);
                //alert((parseInt(rowwidth)+parseInt(currentrowleft)) < totalwidth_current);
                //alert(nextdivwidth);
                //alert(totalwidth_current);

                if((parseInt(rowwidth)+parseInt(currentrowleft)) < totalwidth_current)
                {
                    $("body").find('.rowSubPgm').each(function(index) {
                        //var approx = rowwidth/250;
                        $(this).find('.pgmFirstRow:first').css( "margin-left", "-"+(rowwidth)+"px" );
                    });
                    $(".rows div:nth-child(2)").css( "margin-left", "-"+parseInt(rowleft)-70 );
                }

                if(yellowbg.next().position().top == yellowbg.position().top)
                {
                    $(".div_"+current_col+'_'+current_row).css( "margin-left", "-"+rowleft );
                }
                else
                {             
                    currentrowleft = parseInt(currentrowleft)+rowwidth;
                    var rowleft = currentrowleft+="px";
                    $("body").find('.rowSubPgm').each(function(index) {
                        $(this).find('.pgmFirstRow:first').css( "margin-left", "-"+rowleft );
                    });
                    $(".rows div:nth-child(2)").css( "margin-left", "-"+parseInt(rowleft)-70 );             
                }         
                current_row++;
            }
        }
    }

function createDivs(numberOfDivs)
{
  var programsNumber = 1;
  for(var i=1;i<=numberOfDivs;i++)
  {
    $('.mainWrap').append('<div class="row" id="row'+i+'"><div id="image'+i+'" class="channelList div_'+i+'_1"></div><div class="rowSubPgm"><div id="programe'+(programsNumber++)+'" class="pgmFirstRow div_'+i+'_2"></div><div id="programe'+(programsNumber++)+'" class="pgmFirstRow div_'+i+'_3"></div><div id="programe'+(programsNumber++)+'" class="pgmFirstRow div_'+i+'_4"></div><div id="programe'+(programsNumber++)+'" class="pgmFirstRow div_'+i+'_5"></div></div></div><div class="clear"></div>');
  }
  $(".div_"+current_col+'_'+current_row).addClass( "yellowbg" );
}

function getSchedule($link,j)
{
  //var widthval = 350;
  var widthval =  850;
  var parts = $link.split("/");
  var links = parts[parts.length-1];
  var programlength = 0;

  $.ajax({
  url:$.trim(links),
  type:'GET',
  data:'',
  success: function(data)
  {
    var $data = $(data);        
    var title1 = $data.filter("#title1").html();
    var title2 = $data.filter("#title2").html();
    var title3 = $data.filter("#title3").html();
    var title4 = $data.filter("#title4").html();

    var time1 = $data.filter("#time1").html();
    var time2 = $data.filter("#time2").html();
    var time3 = $data.filter("#time3").html();
    var time4 = $data.filter("#time4").html();
    var time5 = $data.filter("#time5").html();

    time1 = time1.split(" ");
    var time1AMPM = time1[1];
    time1 = time1[0].split(":");
    time1= time1[0]+'.'+time1[1];
    if($.trim(time1AMPM) == 'PM' && time1<12)
      time1 = parseFloat(time1)+12;

      time2 = time2.split(" ");
      var time2AMPM = time2[1];
      time2 = time2[0].split(":");
      time2= time2[0]+'.'+time2[1];
    if($.trim(time2AMPM) == 'PM' && time2<12)
      time2 = parseFloat(time2)+12;

      time3 = time3.split(" ");
      var time3AMPM = time3[1];
      time3 = time3[0].split(":");
      time3 = time3[0]+'.'+time3[1];
    if($.trim(time3AMPM) == 'PM' && time3<12)
      time3 = parseFloat(time3)+12;

      time4 = time4.split(" ");
      var time4AMPM = time4[1];
      time4 = time4[0].split(":");
      time4= time4[0]+'.'+time4[1];
    if($.trim(time4AMPM) == 'PM' && time4<12)
      time4 = parseFloat(time4)+12;

      time5 = time5.split(" ");
      var time5AMPM = time5[1];
      time5 = time5[0].split(":");
      time5= time5[0]+'.'+time5[1];
    if($.trim(time5AMPM) == 'PM' && time5<12)
      time5 = parseFloat(time5)+12;

      var difftime2time1 = (parseFloat(time2) - parseFloat(time1)).toFixed(2);
      var difftime3time2 = (parseFloat(time3) - parseFloat(time2)).toFixed(2);
      var difftime4time3 = (parseFloat(time4) - parseFloat(time3)).toFixed(2);
      var difftime5time4 = (parseFloat(time5) - parseFloat(time4)).toFixed(2);

      if(isNaN(difftime2time1))
      {
        difftime2time1=0;
      }
      if(isNaN(difftime3time2))
      {
    difftime3time2=0;
      }
      if(isNaN(difftime4time3))
      {
    difftime4time3=0;
      }
      if(isNaN(difftime5time4))
      {
    difftime5time4=0;
      } 
      var currenttotal = 0; 
      var firstele = ((j-1)*4)+1; // how many programme i want to output in per block
      var lastele = parseInt(firstele)+3; // how many programme i want to output AFTER the firstele
      var k = 1;
      var programlength = 0;

      for(;firstele <= lastele;firstele++)
      {
        var nexttimedate = parseInt(k)+1;
        programlength = parseFloat(programlength) + parseFloat(eval('difftime'+nexttimedate+'time'+k));
        var a = eval('difftime'+nexttimedate+'time'+k);
        //alert(a);

        if(a >= 0.30 && a <= 0.70)
        {
          $('#programe'+firstele).addClass("span0hr");
          width[j]=250;
        }


        if(a >= 1.00 && a <= 1.29)
        {
          $('#programe'+firstele).addClass("span1hr");
          width[j]=517;
        }

        if(a >= 1.30 && a <= 1.70)
        {
          $('#programe'+firstele).addClass("span1_5hr");
          width[j]=701;
        }

        if(a >= 2.00 && a <= 2.29)
        {
          $('#programe'+firstele).addClass("span2hr");
          width[j]=1311;
        }

        if(a >= 2.30 && a <= 2.70)
        {
          $('#programe'+firstele).addClass("span2_5hr");
          width[j]=1551;
        }

        if(a >= 3.00 && a <= 3.29)
        {
          $('#programe'+firstele).addClass("span3hr");
          width[j]=2051;
        }

        if(a >= 3.30 && a <= 3.58)
        {
          $('#programe'+firstele).addClass("span3_5hr");
          width[j]=2301;
        }

        if(a >= 8.00 && a <= 8.58)
        {
          $('#programe'+firstele).addClass("span8hr");
          width[j]=5244;
        }
        currenttotal++;
    pgmcontent[firstele] = eval('title'+k);
    k++;        
      }
      checksum+=j;

      if(checksuminit == checksum)
      {
        for(var ii=1;ii<width.length-1;ii++)
        {
          widthval+=width[ii];
        }

        for(var jj=1;jj <= pgmcontent.length-1;jj++)
    {
      $('#programe'+jj).html(pgmcontent[jj]);
    }

    for(var kk=1;kk <= imagecontent.length-1;kk++)
    {
      $('#image'+kk).html(imagecontent[kk]);
    }
    $("body").find('.rowSubPgm').each(function(index) {
    $(this).css( "width", widthval+"px");
    });
    $("div").show();    
      }
  }   
  });
}
```

I believe that the problem are somewhere in this code:

```
if (yellowbg.next().length)
            {
                var currentrowleft = $(".rowSubPgm div.pgmFirstRow:first").css( "margin-left").split("px");
                currentrowleft1 = currentrowleft[0].split("-");
                currentrowleft2 = currentrowleft[0].split("-");

                if(typeof(currentrowleft2[1])!= "undefined")
                    currentrowleft = currentrowleft2[1];
                else if(typeof(currentrowleft1[1])!= "undefined")
                    currentrowleft = currentrowleft1[1];
                else
                    currentrowleft = currentrowleft[0];

                var nextdivwidth = $(".div_"+current_col+'_'+(parseInt(current_row)+parseInt(1))).css( "width").split("px");    

                //alert((parseInt(rowwidth)+parseInt(currentrowleft)));
                //alert(totalwidth_current);
                //alert((parseInt(rowwidth)+parseInt(currentrowleft)) < totalwidth_current);
                //alert(nextdivwidth);
                //alert(totalwidth_current);

                if((parseInt(rowwidth)+parseInt(currentrowleft)) < totalwidth_current)
                {
                    $("body").find('.rowSubPgm').each(function(index) {
                        //var approx = rowwidth/250;
                        $(this).find('.pgmFirstRow:first').css( "margin-left", "-"+(rowwidth)+"px" );
                    });
                    $(".rows div:nth-child(2)").css( "margin-left", "-"+parseInt(rowleft)-70 );
                }

                if(yellowbg.next().position().top == yellowbg.position().top)
                {
                    $(".div_"+current_col+'_'+current_row).css( "margin-left", "-"+rowleft );
                }
                else
                {             
                    currentrowleft = parseInt(currentrowleft)+rowwidth;
                    var rowleft = currentrowleft+="px";
                    $("body").find('.rowSubPgm').each(function(index) {
                        $(this).find('.pgmFirstRow:first').css( "margin-left", "-"+rowleft );
                    });
                    $(".rows div:nth-child(2)").css( "margin-left", "-"+parseInt(rowleft)-70 );             
                }         
                current_row++;
            }
        }
```

Do you know how I can move the second and third rows to the left to allow me to move the fourth rows to the left from the right when I press on the keyboard right arrow button??

Comment: Random note: As you are using jQuery, you can throw away the first part of the code and use `$.ajax( ... )` instead.

Comment: yes i am using jQuery. I cant remove the $.ajax in the first part of the code because i need to extract the list of channels from mysql database. Do you know how I can move the second and third rows to the left to allow me to move the fourth rows to the left from the right when I press on the keyboard right arrow button??

Comment: I meant the GetXmlHttpObject() function, which isn't needed for $.ajax and doesn't seem to have a particular purpose if you can use $.ajax. I have looked a bit at the code, but it is giving me a headache and I can't test the code properly on this computer either.

Comment: i have removed the GetXmlHttpObject() function, so why you couldn't help me with my keyboard 37 code to allow me to move on each row for per channel to the left?? i am sure you should know how to move them on each row.

Comment: Because I am forced to use IE on a sluggish computer until I get home. That's why. Although, if I load the webpage, it will eventually load and although some of the items are to the far right of the screen, they will scroll into view for me if I navigate to them. I think you are confusing 'row' and 'column' too. What does it not do, that it should do?

Comment: sorry i meant that the block of The Lead With Jake Tapper should be disappear to the left and a new block next to the The Situation Room to show up from the right, but it won't allow me to move it. can you please help??

Comment: I'll look at it when I am back home.

Comment: ok let me know if you can be able to get the code to working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems. The first problem is that `margin-left` does nothing on `.rowSubPgm`, because the object is not floating. This can be fixed by adding `float: left;` to the CSS for that class. (`display: inline-block;` could possibly be used as an alternative)

In the following piece of javascript you are setting the `margin-left` of two elements. The first element of .pgmFirstRow is the first 'tv-program' of every row. Once the negative margin is equal or greater than the width of that element, further negative margin has no effect. While it made this sort-of work, it would be a headache to implement for every element and it would be much easier to move the entire row. I have no clue why you set the margin of an invisible element at the top, but if you plan on putting anything in there at a later date, you should give their parent element the rowSubPgm class.

```
            if((parseInt(rowwidth)+parseInt(currentrowleft)) < totalwidth_current)
            {
                $("body").find('.rowSubPgm').each(function(index) {
                    //var approx = rowwidth/250;
                    $(this).find('.pgmFirstRow:first').css( "margin-left", "-"+(rowwidth)+"px" );
                });
                $(".rows div:nth-child(2)").css( "margin-left", "-"+parseInt(rowleft)-70 );
            }
```

You need to change this to:

```
            if( (parseInt(rowwidth) + parseInt(currentrowleft)) < totalwidth_current )                 {
                $('.rowSubPgm').css( "margin-left", "-"+(rowwidth)+"px" );
            }
```

If every .rowSubPgm floats, they will (or should) now move to the left and the right as you would expect.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help which it much appreciated. Do you know how I can split the block size 1585 into two different size 701.5 and 701.5 with same programme name on both blocks?

Comment: @Sumurari8: I have forgotten to ask you a question. Do you know how i can resize on per row if the row size is 701px or whatever it is to change to the size i actually want?? if so can you plz tell me what one i should use to find the rows that i want to resize it?

Comment: After reading and re-reading it, I have no clue what you want to happen or what the exact question is.